Extension Selenium IDE for Chrome
When I want to add extension Selenium IDE to the Chrome, it is a notification, that this extension may soon no longer be supported?
Also when I run some test with Selenium Ide through Chrome, sometimes it crashes and I have to remove extension and reload again.

You're seeing the notification because Google Chrome is phasing out Manifest V2, which is what Selenium IDE uses. Manifest V2 support timeline.
According to their GitHub Wiki, "there is no way to transport this functionality to a manifest v3 version of the extension". You can still install it as a package.
